# strange wcf rest error

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

I will start off by saying I am new to wcf and rest.  Here is the situation I have created a wcf service, the service returns an object(person) that contains fields and a collection of order objects.  When I create an instance, the object and the collection of orders gets populated as expected

When I call the same service via rest call returning json see below, the code fails.  if i remove the code where the object is populated, it works.  the json shows and empty set of orders.

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="GetPerson/{user}", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Function GetPerson(ByVal User As String) As Budget
```

The line that fails looks like this

```
lobjPerson.OrderList.Add(order)
```

Order list has been instantiated, and works, but not when called  via rest call returning json

The error i get in the browser is "the error is  kcferrorDomainWinsock:10054".  If i look at with web inspector I can't seem to see an error.  Hopefully this rings a bell for someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem from switching from arraylist to list(of t) for my collections.  I am still pondering why this worked, can anyone explain this?.    Second question remaining is how do you debug rest calls to wcf?  anyone?

Comment: I may be wrong but it sounds like Arraylist is not a serializable object.  I've had a similar problem before and had to parse the arraylist into a List of objects.

Comment: it seems that way, but in the docs :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx The class declaration contains <SerializableAttribute> _  same as list(of t) , so I am confused.